# React 17.0.1 map is undefined

Tags: reactjs

Hi i am trying to create an dynamic table from the json data, which is recieved from Axios get request.

```
const [projectData, setprojectData] = useState({});
const [schedule, setSchedule] = useState({});

useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get(`/fetch-project-details/${id}`, {}).then((response) => {
        setprojectData(result[0]);
        setSchedule(JSON.parse(result[0].p_schedule));
});


return (
    <div>
    schedule.map((value) => { // How to return the key value pairs as a table format
        return (
          <tr>{value.id}</tr>
          <th>{value.keys}</th>
        )
    })
)
```

Here is what i get in **schedule state**

```
[
{
    "Sno": "1",
    "First Name": "name",
    "Last Name": "las2t name",
    "Email": "test@gmail.com",
    "Amount": "2000"
},
{
    "Sno": "1",
    "First Name": "first name",
    "Last Name": "last name",
    "Email": "test2@gmail.com",
    "Amount": "2000"
}
]
```

How to return the key as thead and pairs as tbody ??

Comment: your initial state is not array.

Comment: You also might want to add a dependency list on your `useEffect` so that it won't run on every render. (Which btw causes an infinite render)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// const [schedule, setSchedule] = useState({});
const [schedule, setSchedule] = useState([]);

return (
    <div>
    {
      schedule.map((value) => { 
        return (
          <tr>{value.id}</tr>
          <th>{value.keys}</th>
        )
      })
    }
    </div>
)
```

Comment: Thank you, i am getting this error - Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {......} If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: Wrap the map call in `{}`

Comment: you need to surround the `schedule.map()` part in render within `{}`. This will evaluate the expression within the `{}`.  And also close the `<div>` afterwards

Comment: i have added, can you help me create the table dynamically based on the array object

Answer (score 0):

```
    return is executed before the schedule is set by setSchedule. so you can add a null check in return.
     <div>
       {schedule && ( schedule.map((value) => {
            return (
              <tr>{value.id}</tr>
              <th>{value.keys}</th>
            )
        }) )}

or use ? operator like schedule?.map((value)
```

Comment: how do get the key value pairs to display it in a table with thead and tbody